# Turning off (or otherwise manipulating) the LCD in Linux

Tags: c, linux, system

I just tried the "**2. Starting Steps**" section on [this page](http://leapster.org/linux/cdrom/) as my first code interacting with devices in Linux. I was curious to know if same things can be done with the display, and if so, how. I only know so much about `ioctl()` and I don't know if it applies here, and I'm not sure if the device is available in `/dev` or, rather say, not sure if all the things I'm getting from the example from the link are really relevant here. Where should I begin?

Just to be more clear about what I'm after, as an example to start with, I would like to write a code which would turn the display off and wait for a moment and turn it back on. Hints?

Comment: Try reading about power management functions. BTW ioctl is used for custom API between user mode and kernel mode, sort of like a back door.

Comment: So, does that mean it's irrelevant? It's just that I think that only applies to I/O devices, and I'm not sure if the display is one of those.

Comment: A display is definitely an I/O device.

Comment: I guess ioctl's name was meant to configure drivers from user mode. But every driver or kernel extension has it's own unique ioctl callback (if it has one at all). Performing standard operations for a device are via OS supplied libraries, reading/writing the /dev/something but (almost?) never ioctls. If you there's an ioctl for a specific driver it might not exist in a similar driver.

Answer (score 1):

That varies greatly on the device. Generally, there will be a kernel module for the device, sometimes the single module can support many devices. You can look at the source code to see the ioctl handler. You can find the `file_operations` structure in the driver and look at the function in the `ioctl` position. There you can see what parameters an ioctl command on the device driver will do.

There's no guarantee that ioctl will do anything. The kernel drivers can be implemented in many different ways. But for turning off an LCD screen, ioctl sounds very likely.

I think what you first need to find out is what kernel module supports the device. Then you need to make sure a device file exists for it. You can create the device file using the `mknod` command. After that, you should look through the module's source (probably the header is most relevant), to see what `ioctl` command you need to use to turn the LCD backlight on and off.

Comment: Sorry for the late comment, it was all too much new things for me so I thought I look around a little for what kernel modules are and maybe then look into the source codes of functions and then get back here, well, that was too much to get over in any immediate time. I will do that some day anyway, so thanks.